# Difference in variation of ECEF X and Y data from GNSS

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, ecef

I am logging ECEF data from multiple GNSS receivers and notice that there is always more variance in the the Y (latitude) axis than in the X axis of a scatter plot.  Attached is a plot showing the effect; I have seen this consistently in other data collected over varying time intervals, though in varying amounts, so it doesn't seem to be a temporary effect.

I know that when scaling LLH data, lat and lon degrees aren't of equal size except at the equator, but is there a similar effect in ECEF data, or is there something else that would explain the greater uncertainty in the Y axis?  Is there a conversion factor I should be applying to get an undistorted view of the variance in both axes?

[image: ECEF plot of several GNSS receivers]

The location is approximately 39 44N, -84 11W.

Comment: ECEF Y is not latitude. What are the coordinates of the antenna?

Comment: Hi Luca -- thank you for bringing up one of my uncertainties.  I understand that over the globe X,Y, and Z don't align directly with LLH.  But assuming the area to be plotted is small enough to be considered flat -- e.g., in my case less than 10 meters square -- how *do* you accurately represent north and east on a two dimensional graph?  

In this experiment I'm connecting multiple receivers to a single antenna whose coordinates have been determined by sending multiple-day RINEX from a dual-frequency receiver to NRCan.  The antenna location is approximately

Comment: I was cut off from finishing my comment.  The location is approximately 39 44N, -84 11W.

Comment: ECEF Y coordinates at that location has a large ellipsoidal height component, which I assume is contributing to the error. I'll see if I can write a more precise answer, but for now the location information was indispensable.

Comment: Thank you, Luca.  I think that you're implying the ECEF coordinates have a similar latitude-related distortion as LLH longitude.  That is something I've researched but was never able to find an answer to.  If there's a formula to apply correction to the Y axis based on the magnitude of the X axis, I can apply that to my code.  (BTW, the results from NRCan PPP processing show a similar vertically-oriented ellipse in the uncertainty.  So perhaps they are not making that correction, either.)

Comment: My goal in using ECEF data from the receiver rather than LLH was to avoid converting degrees to meters for display.  Based on the clue you gave me, I found ecef2enuv functions that look like the right tool for that, but they require the observer position to be given in degrees.  I think the observer in my case would be the known antenna location.  If I have to convert that to LLH anyway, am I better off skipping ECEF and just converting receiver LLH data directly to ENU?

Comment: ECEF and ENU are Cartesian 3D systems, there is not any distortion in them. ECEF is the same system for the whole Earth while ENU is relative to a location. Due to the position of the satellites in the trilateration (everyone is up), the error is always greater in the direction of heights. In ENU this error is translated directly into the UP coordinate. But ECEF is not aligned with location, and height contributes to X, Y and Z. Yes, to display relative to location data you would want to use an ENU system aligned to some point within your study area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142935/discussion-between-johnackermann-and-gabriel-de-luca).

Comment: I think expecting variance to be symmetrical in Latitude and Longitude may be invalid.  My feeling is that there are typically more satellites East and West of your location than there are North and South of your location, so Longitude is less variable than Latitude.  Another possible factor - Atmospheric effects are likely to be more similar West and East than Atmospheric conditions North and South also contributing to more variation in Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: Thanks, Trams.  That does make sense, though after I converted to ENU format after Gabriel gave me the clue, the data is now more round than elliptical -- still generally more noise N-S than E-W, but it's a much better match now.

Answer (score 1):

[Gabriel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/133276/gabriel-de-luca) should get credit for this because he sent me in the right direction, but here's what I've learned.  Maybe it's so obvious everyone except me realized it, but I didn't find the answer in my somewhat uninformed searches.

Even though ECEF is measured in meters and seems to correlate X = lon and Y = lat, that is not the case (except maybe at the equator?).  So a 2-dimensional plot of ECEF-X vs ECEF-Y from, say, GPS data will not show a circular pattern with roughly equal variance in both exes.  The effect is to exaggerate the Y scale, causing an elliptical result with a N-S axis.

At my latitude (about 39N) the discrepancy is very noticeable.  A way to address this, at least over small areas (and I'm only interested in less than ~10m x 10m), is to transform to East-North-Up projection.  Doing that causes my GPS data to appear much more symmetrical, though there is still a bit more noise in the N-S plane.  As [Trams](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/54955/trams) suggests, that might be due to more and better satellite positions in the E-W plane than N-S, since I'm far enough north to see the orbital hole around the pole.

I'm using the Python [pymap3d](https://pypi.org/project/pymap3d/) module and its geodetic2enu function to do this.  I originally logged ECEF data from the GPS receiver thinking that would avoid a conversion from LLH degrees to ECEF meters, but geodetic2enu() takes LLH inputs, so it ends up being more direct to use the LLH data messages.